# What is the meaning of "till" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what does" the till" mean in text below? it is from a part of play, setting is in a burgur bar. does it mean " A cash register" or something?

> (Ben is about to dial when Danny raises the bat and brings it down on
>   the phone. A few frenzied blows and it's on the floor in pieces.) Danny:  I'll
>   fuckin' show you what it's about... fuckin' playing with me... fuckin'
>   call the cops... ( He brings the bat down on the till. it rings
>   madly.) Call them!

Comment: _The till_ means 'the box where money is kept' in a store. Dates from before cash registers; it's where change is made.

Comment: A more modern usage of *till* is the drawer in the cash register where the money is kept. Judging from the fact that there's a phone in the play, I expect this is the relevant meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Till in this context means a drawer or a small chest. Till has several meaning and one of those is "A drawer, small chest, or compartment for money, as in a store." Thefreedictionary.com provides 4 different definitions of till:

> Till 1: To prepare (land) for the raising of crops, as by plowing and
>   harrowing; cultivate.
>
> Till 2: Until
>
> Till 3: 1. A drawer, small chest, or compartment for money, as in a
>   store. A supply of money; a purse.
>
> till 4: Glacial drift composed of an unconsolidated, heterogeneous
>   mixture of clay, sand, pebbles, cobbles, and boulders.
>
> Usage Note: **Till and until are generally interchangeable** in both
>   writing and speech, though as the first word in a sentence until is
>   usually preferred: Until you get that paper written, don't even think
>   about going to the movies. Till is actually the older word, with
>   until having been formed by the addition to it of the prefix un-,
>   meaning "up to." In the 1700s, the spelling 'till became fashionable,
>   as if till were a shortened form of until. Although 'till is now
>   nonstandard, 'til is sometimes used in this way and is considered
>   acceptable, though it is **etymologically incorrect.**